# deploy a dacpac that contains a fulltext index with msdeploy

Tags: msdeploy, dacpac, fulltext-index

How to deploy a dacpac that contains a FULLTEXT INDEX (built from a database project) to SQL Server using msdeploy?
MSdeploy skips creation of the fulltext indexes, and fails when creating objects that depend on the (now missing) fulltext indexes.
Is there an hidden option to exclude/include creation of fulltext indexes?

Answer (score 1):

We had same problem with deployment using `sqlpackage`. Root cause is order of statements on building deployment plan with switched on `IncludeTransactionalScripts` option. Depended objects deploy before `full-text` index.

**Solution**

So we just set

```
IncludeTransactionalScripts=False
```

when deployment has new `full-text` index.

Hope it helps.